# Where do I put jstl.jar and standard.jar so that Netbeans don't give errors/warnings?

Tags: netbeans, jstl, taglib

Where do I put `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar` so that Netbeans don't give errors/warnings anymore about the taglib.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for every "3rd party library" which you'd like to use in your webapp, just put them in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of your web project. This way it will automatically be taken in the classpath/buildpath.

You only need to ensure that you have **not** extracted the JAR file(s) and placed its loose contents in the classpath as well and/or hardcoded the taglibs in webapp's own `web.xml`. Some poor online tutorials such as *roseindia* (cough) namely suggests it that way. Don't do that. It will make things only worse.

Then, in your JSP files ensure that you're using the right taglib URI's as outlined in the [JSTL TLD documentation](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/). For example, [JSTL core](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) needs to be declared as follows:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Note the `/jsp` path. It was introduced since JSTL 1.1. The JSTL 1.0 doesn't have the `/jsp` path. If you omit it in JSTL 1.1/1.2, then things won't work. Also note that you should't use the `_rt` suffix such as `/core_rt`, this was the old prototype version.

By the way, in [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) the standard.jar is obsolete. If you want, just delete both the jstl and standard JAR's you currently have and use this single JAR instead (yes, just drop in `/WEB-INF/lib` and anything will go flawlessly).