# JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet strutsAction threw exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, struts-1, stack-overflow, ejb-2.x, jboss-eap-6

I'm migrating my application from Jboss 4 to Jboss 7(jboss eap 6.1 alpha) getting the below error, while trying to search results in my project.
I'm using Java 6, Struts 1.2, EJB 2.0, Jboss 6 EAP alpha.
Note: The same code works fine when running in Jboss 4.0

Server Logs:

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myproject].[strutsAction]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet strutsAction threw exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.IdentityHashMap.maskNull(IdentityHashMap.java:175) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
    at java.util.IdentityHashMap.get(IdentityHashMap.java:314) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.clone(SerializingCloner.java:150) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.clone(SerializingCloner.java:134) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:274) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]


ERROR [org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) ServletException in '/auth/searchresults.do': null: javax.servlet.ServletException: JBWEB000248: Servlet execution threw an exception
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:312) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:832) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:718) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:655) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:940) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:607) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:99) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:135) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:760) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:892) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:462) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.jsp.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsert_005f2(layout_jsp.java:810)
    at org.apache.jsp.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:512)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:365) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:832) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:620) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:553) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:482) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1085) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:263) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:239) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:302) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:832) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:620) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:553) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:482) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1085) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:263) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:398) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:318) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at com.abc.book.web.security.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:72) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at com.planetj.servlet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:270) [pjl-comp-filter-1.7.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.IdentityHashMap.maskNull(IdentityHashMap.java:175) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
    at java.util.IdentityHashMap.get(IdentityHashMap.java:314) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.clone(SerializingCloner.java:150) [jboss-cli-client.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]



ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) JBWEB000313: Exception processing error page /auth/error/error.jsp: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWEB000029: Cannot reset buffer after response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:682) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:702) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:515) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:370) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
```

`$` Layout.jsp `$`

```
    <%@ taglib uri="/bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/logic" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld" prefix="tiles" %>

<html:html lang="false" xhtml="true">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
    <base href="<%= this.getServletContext().getAttribute("baseUrl")%>"></base>
    <tiles:useAttribute name="pagetitle" scope="request" />
    <bean:define id="pagetitle" scope="request" toScope="request" type="java.lang.String"><%=pagetitle.toString()%></bean:define>
    <title><bean:message key="index.page.title" /></title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<html:rewrite page='/style_screen_new.css' />" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<html:rewrite page='/style_header_footer.css' />" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<html:rewrite page='/style_screen_specific.css' />" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="<html:rewrite page='/style_print.css' />" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<html:rewrite page='/style_screen_orders.css' />" />

    <script src="javascript/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="javascript/utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <tiles:useAttribute name="javascriptFormname"/>
    <logic:notEmpty name="javascriptFormname">
        <html:javascript cdata="true" formName="<%=javascriptFormname.toString()%>" staticJavascript="false" scriptLanguage="false"/>
    </logic:notEmpty>
  <tiles:useAttribute name="quickFindFormName"/>
  <logic:notEmpty name="quickFindFormName">
   <html:javascript cdata="true" formName="<%=quickFindFormName.toString()%>" staticJavascript="false" scriptLanguage="false"/>
  </logic:notEmpty>

<%
    String anchor = (String)request.getAttribute("anchor");
 %>  

    <link rel="icon" href="<html:rewrite page='/favicon.ico' />" type="image/ico" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<html:rewrite page='/favicon.ico' />" />         

</head>
<body <%= (anchor == null ? "" : "onLoad=\'location.href=location.href + \"" + anchor + "\";\'" )  %> >

    <tiles:insert attribute="header" flush="true" />
    <%@include file="errors.jsp" %>
    <div id="problemo_div">
        <div id="footer_div">
            <tiles:insert attribute="footer" flush="true" />    
        </div>
        <div id="body_div">
            <tiles:insert attribute="body" flush="true" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html:html>
```

`$` web.xml `$`

```
    <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/html</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
<taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/nested</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
<taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/bean</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
<taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/logic</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
<taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/template</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-template.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

`$` Similar Stackoverflow error in other screen as well `$`

```
    Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: JBWEB004036: File &quot;/auth/error/footer_content.jsp&quot; not found
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:289) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.AppFlterChain.internalDoFilter(AppFlterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.AppFlterChain.doFilter(AppFlterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:832) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:718) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:655) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:940) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.jsp.auth.error.error_jsp._jspService(error_jsp.java:415)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:365) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.AppFlterChain.internalDoFilter(AppFlterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.AppFlterChain.doFilter(AppFlterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:832) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:553) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:482) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:523) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:370) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
```

`$` error_jsp.java `$`

```
    if (_jspx_meth_bean_005fmessage_005f3(_jspx_page_context))
    return;
  out.write("\" onClick=\"history.go(-1);return true;\"> </FORM>\r\n");
  out.write("  \t\t</td>\r\n");
  out.write("  \t</tr>  \t\r\n");
  out.write("</table>\r\n");
  org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(request, response, "footer_content.jsp", out, false);
  out.write("\r\n");
  out.write("\r\n");
  out.write("</body>\r\n");
  out.write("</html>");
} catch (Throwable t) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Struts JSP `layout.jsp` there is a [`<tiles:insert>`](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/struts-tiles/tlddoc/tiles/insert.html) tag that causes Struts to do a loop when Servlet tries to render the page.

Comment: I've commented the line <!--<tiles:insert attribute="header" flush="true" />--> in layout.jsp, but still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I see a bug in Jboss EAP server
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1076572

Comment: Is one of your bean non-serializable?

Comment: Hi, all the required bean classes are serialized, yet getting the same error

Comment: Then paste your `layout.jsp` page and, more or less, show us where the error occur.

Comment: I've pasted the layout.jsp now. But when I commented the line <!--<tiles:insert attribute="header" flush="true" />--> in layout.jsp
the page goes blank, seems its dependent for all the jsp(s) in common. I doubt the issue is not only with this..

Comment: Your taglib configuration seems dodgy. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392993/struts-taglib-directive-in-a-jsp-page-for-tld-provided-by-struts) to configure Struts properly in your project and see if this solves your problem.

Comment: The struts are properly configured, yet getting the similar stackoverflow error in another screen as well... (error.jsp)

Comment: Is there any other way to fix this stackoverflow error?