# How to install jstl.jar and standard.jar in netbeans 7.1.1 & how to solve uri of taglib

Tags: java, jar, netbeans-7

I have just started using Netbeans 7.1.1 and I encountered a problem when I used `taglib`,
it says that the `uri cannot be resolved in web.xml` nor jar files.

What should I do?

Also I found out that this problem can be solved by adding `jstl.jar` and `standard.jstl` in the WEB-INF file. But there was no improvement.

So could someone please suggest how to solve this URI problem??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323645/where-do-i-put-jstl-jar-and-standard-jar-so-that-netbeans-dont-give-errors-warn

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right click your project and Properties->Libraries->Add Library->JSTL 1.1

Comment: does this include the standard.jar as well?