# standard.jar and jstl-1.02 reappearing after deletion

Tags: jar, jstl

I am using jstl-1.2 and as mentioned in this link,
 [Where do I put jstl.jar and standard.jar so that Netbeans don't give errors/warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323645/where-do-i-put-jstl-jar-and-standard-jar-so-that-netbeans-dont-give-errors-warn)

I deleted the obsolete jstl-1.02 and standard.jar from the WEB-INF/lib folder of the webapp.

But once I redeploy the application, the files(deleted jars) appear again in the folder and causing java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: deferredExpression exception.

The exception is
org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.release(ForEachSupport.java:178)

This is the tag directive I have used. 
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

Please help.

Answer (score -1):

These jars are coming with Netbeans default , arent that?

Comment: No emrerme. I copied them from tomcat folder and pasted them under my project.